# ACID transaction in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, transactions, rabbitmq, amqp

Using node.js I'd like to read a RabbitMQ queue and write the message to a MongoDB database.  How do I wrap the read and the write within an ACID transaction so the whole thing either works or fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongo recommends emulate two-phase commit with the following pattern:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/

Also it is already implemented:

https://github.com/rystsov/mongodb-transaction-example